# Initializing array of strings for callback in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access an array of strings in my application and receive the error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I go back to my code and find out that no matter what I do, when I'm trying to access the array of strings that the object continuously returns nil:

```
class Foo
   attr_reader :bar
   def initalize
     @bar = ['a','b','c']
   end  
 end  

> a = Foo.new
=> #<KeywordsController::Foo:0x007fa3541b3920>
> a.bar
=> nil
```

How do I create a class where I can access the array of strings?

Comment: You have mis-spelled `initialize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo
   attr_reader :bar
   def initialize
     @bar = ['a','b','c']
   end  
 end
```

One of those madness-inducing typos that you cannot see whilst looking for weirder and weirder problems!

Comment: In the foobar example, it should work with just `attr_reader`. You just had misspelled `initialize`.